# Angular 4 ngx-treeview integration with json response

Tags: angular, treeview, treeviewitem

I'm currently new to angular 4 and using ngx-treeview(https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-treeview) to get the tree structure. Using static data able to bind view the tree.

But need to use the rest service to get the tree structure hence created a similar class TreeviewItem from ngx-treeview

```
public class TreeviewItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public bool Collapsed { get; set; }
    public TreeviewItem[] Children { get; set; }
}
```

Here is json response which i'm getting

```
[{"text":"Core Fields","value":100,"collapsed":false,"children":null}]
```

Angular service:

```
return this.http.get(this.appHelpersSvc.apiAddress + 
"api/module/getStandardFields", { headers: httpHeaders })
.map((response:Response) => <TreeviewItem>response.json());
```

Angular Component

```
itemsList: TreeviewItem[]; 
this.moduleService.getStandardFields().subscribe(data => {this.itemsList = data;});
```

Doing so i'm getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.items[i].getCheckedItems is not a function
at TreeviewComponent.getCheckedItems (http://localhost:4001/main.bundle.js:42763:107)
at TreeviewComponent.raiseSelectedChange (http://localhost:4001/main.bundle.js:42745:34)
at TreeviewComponent.ngOnChanges (http://localhost:4001/main.bundle.js:42703:22)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (http://localhost:4001/vendor.dll.js:12160:19)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (http://localhost:4001/vendor.dll.js:13586:17)
at checkAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:4001/vendor.dll.js:13525:16)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:4001/vendor.dll.js:14228:59)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (http://localhost:4001/vendor.dll.js:14169:13)
```

not able to understand what is going wrong.
thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9):

I am author of this component.
You need to map your JSON to list of TreeviewItem:

```
const list = items.forEach(item => new TreeviewItem(item));
```

and then binding list to component.

Comment: Hi, Leo Vo, You made a great tool, may i know how can i uncheck all the checkbox by default.

Comment: Hello, how can I set checkbox values when I get checked items values from Database ?  I'm trying to do that: this.values  = this.claims.map(x => x.checkedId);  but no result. can you help me ? thank you

Comment: I am also having dynamic json but not acceptable by ngx-trreview. It only accepts it's interface's property. Should I convert my json in required treeview format ? Or is there any way like whatever json we get from response we get a treeview like UI ?

Answer (score 1):

what is `items` in your code? why did you create `TreeviewItem` class with three properties in it? Did you try to make new `TreeviewItem` type and make cast to it to make json work? I do not think you need it because there is already `TreeviewItem`.

Anyway, try do `new TreeviewItem(json)` (where `json` is json string you get from server) instead of casting to `TreeviewItem`. But do this in component, not in service. Remove the casting in service. Leave the service with return of `any`.
By the way, if you do the cast, you should do it in component and not in service. Should be more efficient, unless you are going to get only treeviews in every requests.

I am not pro, but I think you should not use cast just because you know that it is possible. If there is a way of creating object you should create it. By the way, there is documentation with an example of creating new item.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.itemsList = data.map(value => {
            return new TreeviewItem({text: value.name, value: value.id, collapsed: true, children: filterChildren});
        });
```

use map method to iterate and create a new TreeView object and pass json object to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by doing like this

```
ngOnInit() { 
   this.service.getTreeViewdata() 
      .subscribe( items => 
                     this.items = items, error => 
                        this.errorMessage = error, () => 
                           this.fillitemdata()
      ); 
      debugger;
}

private fillitemdata(): void { this.items = this.getData(); }

getData(): any[] { const itCategory = new TreeviewItem(this.items[0]); return [itCategory]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution looks like this:

```
private generateTreeviewItemArray(categories: Category[]): TreeviewItem[] {
    let treeViewItems: TreeviewItem[] = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < categories.length; index++) {
      treeViewItems.push(new TreeviewItem({
          text: categories[index].name,
          value: categories[index].id
        } as TreeItem
      ));
    }
    return treeViewItems;
}
```

I create a new `TreeviewItem` using its constructor, where I create from the `Category` item a new `Treeview` object.